# Variable undefined in Service, after saving a value in it (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I'm writing a phone directory app with Cordova and thus using AngularJs for the logic.
I'm using this service to connect to the server (its a Diffusion Push server) and sending/recieving the messages with the data.

```
angular.module('directory.services', [])

.service('EmployeeService', function() {
    var clientSession;
    var employees = [];

    this.initConnection = function() {
        diffusion.connect({
            host : 'localhost',
            port : 8080,
            secure : false,
            principal : 'admin',
            credentials : 'password'
         }).then(function(session) {
             clientSession = session;
            session.on({
                [...] // Lots of session listerners
            });
           var subscription = session.subscribe('Company/Test');
           var stream = session.messages.listen('Company/Test');

           stream.on('message', function(message) {
               //Called when a message is recieved
                employees = JSON.parse(message.content);
                console.log(employees);
               // log shows me the data fine here
           });
        });
    }        

    this.sendMessage = function(content){
        clientSession.messages.send('Company/Test', content);
    }

    this.clearResult = function(){
        employees= []; 
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('directory.controllers', [])

.controller('empListCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicPlatform, EmployeeService) {
    $scope.employees = EmployeeService.employees;
    $scope.searchKey = "";

    $scope.clearSearch = function () {
        // console.log() gives "undefined" for both variables here
        $scope.searchKey = "";
        EmployeeService.clearResult();            
    }

    $scope.search = function () {
        EmployeeService.sendMessage($scope.searchKey);
    }

    EmployeeService.initConnection();   
});
```

Problem:
I get the value from the server stream, and save it in my service variable.
But when I call clearSearch() from the controller, both employees variables are undefined, in the scope and in the service.

I get that there might be an error with the linking, but shouldnt then atleast the service still have the data?

I tried using an Object with an nested array for the linking, and tried to use watch in the controller. Both didnt work.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Reproduce it via jsbin.com please.

Comment: @FrankFang: The proxy here is blocking the site. But I will try to when I get home

Comment: At which point exactly you get an error, acc. to me this line `$scope.employees = EmployeeService.employees;` is incorrect as `employees` variable in `EmployeeService` is private. Please confirm

Comment: @MithleshKumar I get a js error "element not found" after recieving a message. Before that no errors at all. When logging scope and service variable to console at the start of the clearSearch function, I get "undefined" for both

Comment: @Cevera please check my below comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I see is that `var employees = [];` is not bound to anything. So how could you expect to access it via `EmployeeService.employees`?

Second thing is that your service does not return anything. If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) you can see the service that is injected to your controller takes the value of what is returned from the service.

This is generally how you would build a service:

```
angular.module('app', []).service('helloService', function() {
  var Service = function() { /* INIT CODE HERE */ };

  Service.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    console.log('hello, world;')
  };

  return new Service();
})
```

You could also return an object literal, a string, a function, pretty much anything but the point is that you return something. You're just binding methods  it to `this`.

Third thing is that `EmployeeService.initConnection()` is an asynchronous call there's no guarantee that the connection is initialized by the time you call `sendMessage()`. This is OK but you need to make sure the connection is ready by the time you trigger either of the service methods. You can do this by blocking interaction until a promise is resolved.

```
// controller template scope
<button ng-click="sendMessage()" ng-disabled="connecting">Send Message</button>

// controller
$scope.connecting = true;
EmployeeService.initConnection().then(function() {
   $scope.connecting = false;
});

// service
.service('EmployeeService', ['$q', function() {
  var clientSession;
  var employees = [];
  var service = {}

  service.initConnection = function() {
    var defer = $q.defer();

    // do this in connection success callback
    defer.resolve();

    // do this if the connection fails
    dewfer.reject();

    return defer.promise;  
  }

  return service;
}]);
```

That's about all the advice I can give until you are more specific.

---

Edit: You can watch your service for updates like so:

```
$scope.watch(
  function() { return service.currentResult() },
  function(employees) {
    $scope.employees = employees;
  }
);
```

This will always keep `$scope.employees` up to date every digest cycle.

Comment: First thanks for the elaborate answer. After using your structur and `var service = {currentResult: null};` as my storage variable I can now access the values from within my controller. Only thing not working is the binding, so `$scope.employees` gets updated when my `service.currentResult` changes

Comment: No worries. Check my edit. I think that should work for you. I obviously can't test without a demo.

Comment: Works fine. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to put the employee as a specific index of your array

```
stream.on('message', function(message, id) {
  //Called when a message is recieved
  employees[id] = JSON.parse(message.content);
  console.log(employees);
});
```

Thats if you have a load of employees that you add one at a time. But maybe I'm misunderstanding your code.

Comment: I am using the server to search a list of employees, and the data I get back is a JSON with all employees that match the searchterm. I am overriding the value every time the user searches with the new results.

Comment: what does your JSON array look like in the browser?
you have a link or is it just local host?

Comment: Only have it on localhost, but it basically looks like the respone from the first example http://yonik.com/solr-json-request-api since its also a Solr response. I copy-pasted the JSON into my controller to test my html view, and it worked. So the JSON itself should be ok

Comment: I'm sure the JSON is fine, I was just wondering how many arrays and objects you had in it.

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.employees` is undefined because `EmployeeService.employees` is `undefined`.

In `EmployeeService` your should declare it as follow `this.employees=[ ]` so that you can access it globally.

Now for `undefined` case in `clearResult` function, add some dummy value to variable `this.employees` and try to access it `clearResult` function.

Use breakpoints to get step by step code checking.

I hope this will help you.
Thanks